# Stack Template Arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

#### Focus on the template arguments

I can create a stack (an adapter class template from standard library) object like this,

```
stack<int, vector<int>> myStack;
```

I know the second template argument means the underlying data structure of the stack. But why the following line doesn't give a compile time error?

```
stack<int, vector<string>> myStack;
```

Notice that I'm declaring a stack to contain elements of type `int`, but at the same time I'm declaring the underlying data structure to hold `string` elements.

Functionally, It works as if it was a stack of string elements.

Comment: Copying a note from cppreference: _The behavior is undefined if T is not the same type as Container::value_type. (since C++17)_. In your case, `Container::value_type == string` and `T == int`.

Comment: oh man. I got it ^_^ Thanks a lot man. Meaning the behavior is not guaranteed. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**What you are doing is undefined behaviour. Nevertheless, I am going to explain why it seems to work fine.**

The container adapter `std::stack<T, TContainer>` contains several type symbols that are aliases for types that will be commonly used. There is a list [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack).

One that concerns us here is `std::stack::value_type`. It basically determines what type the methods `std::stack::push` and friends expect:

```
void push( const value_type& value );
```

We can also see how it is defined:

```
using value_type = typename TContainer::value_type
```

So, the type that is used in all actions is actually only based on the second type, `TContainer` ! In your case, that is `vector<string>::value_type`, so `value_type` will be an alias to `string`. The type used for `T`, `int` in your case, is not used.
Thus, everything **seems** to work.

**But** even though this works in **your** case with **your** particular compiler, it is actually not allowed:

> The behavior is undefined if T is not the same type as Container::value_type. (since C++17)

You can find the source for this quote [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack).

Comment: Not the OP, but I would like to know why it was left as UB, and not required to be an error with some `static_assert`s.

Comment: @Dan M: I do not know the exact reasoning behind this, but it is often done this way in the standard. I guess it is to give the implementation some freedom. But since it is UB an implementation might choose to issue a diagnostic.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> T   -   The type of the stored elements. The behavior is undefined if T is not the same type as Container::value_type. (since C++17)

Undefined behaviour means it might compile, it might even work, or it might wipe your hard drive.

How it fails, if it does, is implementation dependant.

Comment: Wipe my hard drive :D I understood the concept, thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I would imagine that your implementation is discarding the `int` template argument, and just uses `Container::value_type` instead.

Once we get to C++17, this will be explicitly illegal. Some compilers will already not appreciate this code..

For example:

```
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::stack<int, std::vector<std::string>> s;
    s.push(3);
}
```

Fails to compile under OS X (clang, libc++, c++11) with:

```
blah.cc:7:7: error: no matching member function for call to 'push'
    s.push(3);
    ~~^~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/stack:194:10: note: 
      candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'const value_type' (aka
      'const std::__1::basic_string<char>') for 1st argument
    void push(const value_type& __v) {c.push_back(__v);}
         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/stack:197:10: note: 
      candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'value_type' (aka 'std::__1::basic_string<char>') for
      1st argument
    void push(value_type&& __v) {c.push_back(_VSTD::move(__v));}
         ^
1 error generated.
```